# Pattern Recognition in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I have a simple template grayscale image, with white background and black shape over it, and I have several similar test images, I want to compare these two images and see if template matches any of the test images. Can you please suggest a simple(easy to use) pattern recognition library for C++ which takes two images and compares them and shows the result?

Comment: Are you searching strictly for identical images, or scaled/rotated/translated versions of an image that might be corrupted by noise, compression artifacts, or other defects? What exactly does it mean to "match"?

Comment: the scale is same , the rotation and translation can be different . there is no noise , no defects .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do image1-image2 for all pixels. Then sum up all the differences. The lower the results, the closer the images.

If your pattern could be of several sizes, then you have to resize it and check it for each positions.

Comment: You should specify that you either need to square the difference or take its absolute value.  Squaring is more common.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a Neural Network on the image. Inputs should be the greyscales of your image. you should train your network to a train set, chose proper regularization parameters using a cross validation set, and finally test your network on a test set.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13582/Back-propagation-Neural-Net

(I have done this myself to train a network to recognise hand written digits - it works very well.)

Comment: while I am a H.U.G.E proponent of ANNs and try to use them in any possible situation, they may be overkill for OP's problem. If he is dealing with many/most of the distortions @twalberg brought up, then yes, ANNs would do very well at cutting through the noise. However, a simple 2D cross correlation might be enough for a B&W image match with little distortion. image subtraction a la bokan would work for only the most exact cases.

Answer (score 1):

How simple the library you need is depends on the specific parameters of your problem.  [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a great image processing library that should be able to do what you need it to.  [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#template-matching) is a tutorial on template matching in OpenCV.  It makes it very easy to switch between matching metrics and choose the best one for your problem.

Comment: Is this template matching solution rotation and scale invariant ?

Comment: I don't believe so, if you need those then [one of these](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html) tutorials would be a better option.  You detect features in your object and match them all.  Then with a set of point correspondences you can get rotation and scale.